# non divergence form vs divergence form operator

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, partial-differential-equations

Can the non divergence form operator $\mathcal{L}u= u_{xx}+u_{yy} + u_x=\Delta u + u_x$ be put in divergence form? In general, can any constant coefficient non divergence form operator be put into divergence form?

Comment: http://home.iitk.ac.in/~tmk/courses/minicourse/FAPDE/BasicPDE.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To put an operator into divergence form we multiply $Lu$ by a function $\varphi $ and integrate by parts to get rid of the second derivatives of $u$. This works as long as the coefficients of second derivatives are sufficiently smooth, and constant functions are *very* smooth.